# How to run Deep_sort on yolov4-tiny on webcam?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, object-tracking

I am trying to run deep-sort for real-time object tracking on yolov4-tiny model on webcam from this github repository.

https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-deepsort

But there is only command for yolov4 for real time object detection using webcam. How can I modify the code and what will be the command to run on yolov4-tiny to run on webcam for real time object detection.

I will be glad if you suggest me some other way to run object tracking(less resource hungry way) or in tensorflow lite.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on the setup page https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-deepsort. You don't need to make changes you just need to get the right weights and then run it pointing to the correct weights like:

{#Run yolov4-tiny object tracker
python object_tracker.py --weights ./checkpoints/yolov4-tiny-416 --model yolov4 --video ./data/video/test.mp4 --output ./outputs/tiny.avi --tiny}

You can look at the yolov4.py code and you will seen how it checks for normal or tiny when you give it the command line string see https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-deepsort/blob/master/core/yolov4.py.